# Javascript Snake Collision Understanding

Tags: javascript

I need help with understanding this part of code with Snake collision in javascript, I marked parts that I do not fully understand how they work:
Full code at:
https://codeincomplete.com/posts/starting-snakes/

```
// do not understand this function
function occupies(a, b)   {
    return a && b && (a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y);
}; 

//do not understand this function 
function snakeOccupies(pos, ignoreHead) {
    var segment = ignoreHead ? head.next : head;
    do {
        if (occupies(segment, pos))
            return true;
    } while (segment = segment.next);
    return false;
};

function unoccupied() {
    var pos = {};
    do {
        //understand this part but i do not understand what does while do
        pos.x = Math.round(random(0, nx-1));
        pos.y = Math.round(random(0, ny-1));
    } while (foodOccupies(pos) || snakeOccupies(pos));
    return pos;
};
```

Comment: What parts of it don't you understand? Is it about the syntax? Or about what it does? Do you know how linked lists work?

Comment: Kind of both, I understand syntax but  I dont know what it does exactly for the marked parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, a position on the game area is represented by an object with properties `x` and `y`.

`occupies` checks whether two such objects represent the same position. It's not sufficient to just `return a == b;` or `return a === b;`, because separate objects can be copies of each other and represent the same position. For example, the expression `{ x: 1, y: 1 } === { x: 1, y: 1 }` will evaluate to `false`.

The `a && b &&` part is to handle the case where one/both of the arguments `a` and `b` is `undefined` or `null` or something. If `a` is falsy, `occupies` will return `a`. If `a` is truthy but `b` is falsy, it will return `b`. (In javascript, the values `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''` and `NaN` are falsy; all others are truthy.) Since the return value is only used inside an `if(...)`, any falsy value is treated as `false` and any truthy value is treated as `true`.

The do-while loop in `unoccupied` runs the contents of the block, then evaluates `foodOccupies(pos) || snakeOccupies(pos)`. If it evaluates to `true` (or otherwise truthy) it will run the block again; otherwise it will stop. It will keep running the loop until the condition is falsy. The only difference between this and a while loop without `do` is that this one will not check the condition before the first iteration of the loop (so it's guaranteed to run the block at least once).

The loop in `snakeOccupies` is slightly unusual: the condition (`segment = segment.next`) doesn't just return a value which is checked for truthiness, it also changes the value of a variable.

`head` is the position of the snake's head. It has properties `x` and `y`, just like the other positions, except that it also contains a property called `next`. The value of this property is another position, representing the next square after the snake's head, which has its own `next` property referencing the next position on the snake, and so on. This is what Bergi meant about a "linked list": It's a sequence of (`x`, `y`) pairs, and could have been implemented as an array, but instead it's implemented by links between the elements.

So the do-while loop iterates over the positions in the snake (possibly ignoring `head`). If it reaches one positioned at `pos`, `snakeOccupies` returns `true`. Otherwise, the loop will eventually reach the end of the snake, `segment` will be set to something falsy (probably `undefined` or `null`), the loop will be exited and `snakeOccupies` will return `false`.